# PHP(CodeIgniter) continua a enviar email mesmo com os dados do servidor do mail errados

Tags: php, codeigniter

Portanto, no meu sistema de login tenho uma zona em que o utilizador pede para recuperar a password e é-lhe enviado um email com a nova password. 
Ao testar o código, reparei que se alterar os dados do meu servidor de email, o email continua a ser enviado sem dar qualquer erro.

Alguem sabe o porquê de isto acontecer?

Código:

```
$servidoremail = file(APPPATH.'libraries/connections/servidoremail.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
      $sname= $servidoremail['0'];
      $suser= $servidoremail['1'];
      $spass= $servidoremail['2'];
      $sport= $servidoremail['3'];
      $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
      $user = $this->Usuario_model->getuserbyemail($email);
      if(isset($user)){
        $novasenha =addslashes(substr(md5(time()), 0, 6));
        $this->Usuario_model->updatepass($novasenha,$email);
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['mailpath']         = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
        $config['smtp_host']        = $sname;
        $config['smtp_auth']        = true;  
        $config['smtp_user']        = $suser;
        $config['smtp_pass']        = $spass= $servidoremail['2'];
        $config['smtp_port']        = $sport;
        $config['smtp_auto_tls']    = true;
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->from('portal@samsic.pt');
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject('Nova password');
        $this->email->message('Nova senha: '.$novasenha);

        if($this->email->send()){
          $data['resposta'] = 'Password alterada, verifique o seu email';
          $data['tipo'] = 'bg-success';
          $this->load->view('recuperarpassword',$data);

        }else{
          echo $this->email->print_debugger();
          //$data['resposta'] = 'Erro ao enviar email';
          //$data['tipo'] = 'bg-danger';
          //$this->load->view('recuperarpassword',$data);
        }
```

Comment: Não dá para identificar muita coisa porque a função está incompleta. O array `$config` está sendo usado em qual lugar do seu código?

Comment: Tem razão, já reformulei o texto. Continua a enviar o email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, já resolvi o problema. Eu tinha criado um ficheiro config/email.php onde tinha inserido os dados por código direto.
Quando este ficheiro existe, não se torna necessário utilizar "$this->email->initialize()" sendo que mesmo utilizando-o, este é ignorado (parto eu do pressuposto dado que era o que me estava a acontecer). https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: Marque a resposta pra pergunta não ficar aberta.